# Trigger doesn’t work for dynamic content added on .change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, callback

I append some HTML dynamically, once an `<input>` field has changed. When I click on `<a href="" class="js-remove-item">` link I want to remove that item. Yet the trigger for that link doesn’t happen.

I tried adding the class name `.tvshow` of the `<input>` to the data handler like so:

From this:

```
$('.js-remove-item').on('click touchstart', function() {
```

to this:

```
$('.js-remove-item').on('click touchstart', '.tvshow', function() {
```

Yet, it’s not working. What is going on?

Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7tGCh/ (try typing something in the input and blur it, then click on link to remove that item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is inserted dynamically, so you'll need to delegate the event :

```
$('.container__list-of-movies').on('click touchstart', '.js-remove-item', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('remove-tv-show');
  window.setTimeout(function() {$('.remove-tv-show').remove();}, 500);

  alert('removing');
  return false
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tGCh/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works! What if I have a calculation inside of `$('.js-adjust-percentage').each(function() {` and I load some content dynamically (`.js-adjust-percentage` is in there) like so: `$('body').append($("<div>").load(linkUrl, function(){}).addClass('js-dialog'));`? I tried: `$('.js-dialog').each('.js-adjust-percentage', function() {`